# C# Как связать MonthCalendar c dataGridview

Tags: c#, winforms

Задумал сделать календарь напоминаний. Хочу связать компонент MonthCalendar c dataGridview. Как это реализовать? Ну вроде так как картинке!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По сути это форма с табами или закладками как удобно и на каждом отображается grid view. Забудьте про календарь и сделайте view потом закладки.

Comment: Связь делается элементарно. Вводится свойство date на него смотрит календарь и grid при изменении date вызывается рефреш календарь и grid

Comment: Может есть хотя бы какой то пример?